# minzoom seems not to work with custom layers in mapbox

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have used the mapbox example from [Add a 3D model](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/) but when I add `minzoom : 17,` property the layer definition is not hidden once the zoom out is lower, but it works well with other fill or fill extrusion layers. 
Is this a know bug or by design decision?

Here's the test [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mpotsqy/1/)

Comment: This may be a bug worth reporting.

Comment: Thansk @SteveBennett, I've read you blog many times... I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it run, but must be after the layer is created through addLayer. You must execute setLayerZoomRange explicitly, the attribute in the addLayer creation doesn't work for custom layers.
`map.setLayerZoomRange('layername', 17, 24);`